# "Unknown error" with HAXM in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

It was working well...
But the problem started recently
When I press "Run" I get the following error message
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AvGn.png)
intel haxm is required to run this avd unknown error

Although the haxm is already installed, I deleted it and installed it more than 15 times
[sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQCoe.png)

I installed it from inside Android Studio, and from outside, I tried copying and pasting it into the sdk files
But the problem continues

I checked the BIOS emulation settings

I checked the Hyper-V settings in the features in the control panel

I do not have an anti virus and I disabled Windows Defender

I have an Intel processor

Older HAXM versions also tried the same problem

I have read all the discussions on the site but it is of no use

I Tried to reinstall Android Studio and still the same problem

Comment: can you try to [run emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) and see if it prints any error?

Comment: Try uninstalling Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all Sdk, gradle and HaXM and re-downloaded it again
And everything worked fine.